# Getting values out of a mongoose function (node JS)

Tags: node.js, database, mongoose, undefined

I think I have misunderstood something fundamental about mongoose here.
I'm using .find() with mongoose to get a value from a DB but it's being returned as undefined when it exits the call back. Is there a way to pass this value out?

Thank you in advance,
Tim

```
function getNumberOfRegisteredPupils(sProg){
  var numberOfPupils;
  User.find({studyProgram: sProg}, (err, users)=>{
    console.log(users.length); //logs correct value to terminal 
    return users.length; //returns undefined
    
  });
}
```

Comment: use async / await in your function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `getNumberOfRegisteredPupils` doesn't return anything (there is no `return` statement in that function, only inside a callback of `User.find` function!), hence `undefined`.

You want to either return a promise:

```js
function getNumberOfRegisteredPupils(sProg){
  return User.find({studyProgram: sProg}, (err, users)=>{
    return users.length;
  });
}
```

Or you can use async/await syntax as suggested in the comments:

```js
async function getNumberOfRegisteredPupils(sProg){
  const users = await User.find({studyProgram: sProg}).exec();
  return users.length;
}
```

OT: However, if you are looking for getting only number of users, have a look at `Model.count()` [[docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.count)].

Comment: Ahh, yes that makes sense.

This doesn't return the length of that array though, it return details about my whole database. 
Is there a reason for this?

Thank you so much for your help, 
Tim

Comment: @Tburgum I tested the answer locally with and without filters and it works fine (returns correct number of results). I suggest to open a new question if needed.